# Getting Angular to Play Well with cluetip (a jquery plugin)

Tags: angularjs

I've got some example code in plunkr that has two issues (I know of).  The first, is I can not get the cluetip code to run in the ng-repeater loop, and the other (which is what I really thought would be the issue) is that I can't figure out how to have the {{ mynum }} evaluate in the ajax5.html template that gets loaded.  I have the plnkr example here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/SQ5eT630d3GVwYCej9te?p=preview and the code in the plnkr.

Using ajax.html as template

```
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div ng-repeat='mynum in myarray'>

   <br/>
  <a style="" title="" class="basic" href="ajax.html" rel="ajax5.html">Using ajax.html as template</a>
    <br/>
    <a id=MyId{{mynum}} style="" title="" class="basic" href="ajax.html" rel="ajax5.html">This is link number {{mynum}}</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>

  </div>
 <hr/>
  <input ng-model="somedata" placeholder="Some Data">
  <br/>{{ somedata }}

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a class="title" href="#" title="This is the title| someData: {{ somedata }} .|In this case, the delimiter is a pipe">In Line Text</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a class="nottitle" href="#" title="This is the title| someData: {{ somedata }} .|In this case, the delimiter is a pipe">In Line Text</a>
  <br/>

  <script type="application/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('a.title').cluetip({
        splitTitle: '|'
      });
    });

    $('a.basic').cluetip();

    $('#MyId1').cluetip();
    $('#MyId2').cluetip();
    $('#MyId3').cluetip();
  </script>
```

...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.somedata = 'someValue';
  $scope.myarray = [1,2,3];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

At the time your inline scripts execute, Angular has not yet rendered the items in the ng-repeat, so the `#MyId1`, `#MyId2`, and `#MyId3` elements do not exist in the DOM and can't have cluetip initialised on them.

Due to the asynchronous nature of Angular and unknowns around when specific DOM objects get rendered and become accessible, the proper way to approach this is to avoid targetting specific elements by classes or IDs and wrap your plugins with directives.

For example:

```
app.directive('basicClueTip', function () {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).cluetip({splitTitle: '|'});
    }
  };
  return directive;
});
```

Can be used as this in your HTML:

```
<a basic-clue-tip href="" title="hello">Basic cluetip</a>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9s01wgIqkgi5S6cuyPnV?p=preview

2.

To evaluate the `{{mynum}}` and `{{somedata}}` bindings, it's first important to understand that any piece of HTML inserted into DOM *outside of Angular* will not automatically be brought into Angular's care.

In this case, cluetip retrieves and inserts its own tooltip HTML but nothing here notifies Angular that this has happened.

To make this work, you need a way to configure the plugin so that you can call Angular's `$compile` service to link the tooltip's HTML with the directive's scope and hence make the bindings "live".

I don't know the specifics of the cluetip API, but the code could look something like this.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  $(element).cluetip({
    splitTitle: '|'
    ...
    // pseudo code
    // after retrieving HTML, and before showing the tooltip
    //   onCluetipHTMLRetrieved(retrievedHTML);
    // pseudo code
    ...
  });
  function onCluetipHTMLRetrieved (cluetipHTML) {
    $compile(cluetipHTML)(scope);
  }
}
```

If the cluetip API does not let you do this, then perhaps it's a better option to use a different tooltip library that already has Angular directives made for them e.g. UI-Bootstrap or Angular-Strap

Read more about $compile: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile